# Wait for on('data') to finish while using pipe in nodejs

Tags: typescript, stream, pipe

I have a stream, say `s1`. Now I want the `demo` function in the following code to complete execution before another `on(data ...` is executed.

```
s1.on(data, async data =>{
await demo();
})
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: This is known Promisification. It adapts callback APIs to Promise based ones.

Comment: Means can you tell me a way to achieve this

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize what you were asking for. I don't think you can do that without writing an adapter for the event emitter.